# Batch File - Compare Directories and Create a List of Non-Duplicate files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm writing a batch file that I will use to compare the contents of two directories, and for every file that is in one directory but not in another, I will send an email with those. I am using a little program called WatchDirectory to aid in this, and have set up the following in the .bat file that it uses to send an email. This is included for completeness, but my question comes afterward.

```
set EMAILFILE="c:\ProgramData\watchDirectory\System.Mail\Out\emailfile.txt"
echo ATTENTION: Files from DMZ not processed by AMS > "%EMAILFILE%"
echo Wally Williams^<wwilliams@ny-tst.com^> >> "%EMAILFILE%"

rem !!!!!   important line !!!!!
echo list of files not processed goes here.... >> "%EMAILFILE%"

rem WatchDirectory will automatically send out emails for files with wdmail extension
ren "%EMAILFILE%" DMZAMS_%RANDOM%_%RANDOM%.wdmail
```

My question: Currently I simply check the two directories as follows

```
for %%i in ("\\sc0189v\d$\APPS\ACH_CANADA\Archive\RECV\201811\*") do if not exist "folder1\%%~nxi" echo %%i File not processed by AMS > results.txt
```

and create a file with the names.

EDIT: currently I do not do anything with with results.txt file containing file names. I want to insert these names into %%EMAILFILE%% instead. I want to put those into the above email instead of the line

```
echo list of files not processed goes here.... >> "%EMAILFILE%"
```

I want to echo out a list of files, one per line. Thanks.

Comment: In your `for` statement `. . . echo %%i>>"%EMAILFILE%"` ???

Comment: You might be interested in [`robocopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) for this task (particularly its options `/L` and `/E`)...

Comment: @avery_larry see EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question and your edit, I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want.  My comment was proposing the following:

```
set "EMAILFILE=c:\ProgramData\watchDirectory\System.Mail\Out\emailfile.txt"
echo ATTENTION: Files from DMZ not processed by AMS > "%EMAILFILE%"
echo Wally Williams^<wwilliams@ny-tst.com^> >> "%EMAILFILE%"

rem !!!!!   important line !!!!!
for %%i in ("\\sc0189v\d$\APPS\ACH_CANADA\Archive\RECV\201811\*") do if not exist "folder1\%%~nxi" echo %%i>>"%EMAILFILE%"

rem WatchDirectory will automatically send out emails for files with wdmail extension
ren "%EMAILFILE%" DMZAMS_%RANDOM%_%RANDOM%.wdmail
```

Comment: I am completely new to .bat scripting. That was indeed all I needed to do. Thanks!